# What is a simple way of computing the following fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math

Compute the value of the expression:

$$\frac{(10^4+324)(22^4+324)(34^4+324)(46^4+324)(58^4+324)}{(4^4+324)(16^4+324)(28^4+324)(40^4+324)(52^4+324)}$$

Comment: Use graphing calculator.

Comment: All numbers on the top and bottom are divisible by 4, so you could cancel that out. Other than that, im not sure what would cancel easily.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%2810%5E4%2B324%29%2822%5E4%2B324%29%2834%5E4%2B324%29%2846%5E4%2B324%29%2858%5E4%2B324%29%7D%7B%284%5E4%2B324%29%2816%5E4%2B324%29%2828%5E4%2B324%29%2840%5E4%2B324%29%2852%5E4%2B324%29%7D) was pretty simple.

Comment: [Sophie Germain Identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1987_AIME_Problems/Problem_14)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that
$$x^4+324=(x^2-6x+18)(x^2+6x+18).$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{(n+6)^4+324}{n^4+324}
&= \frac{((n+6)^2-6(n+6)+18)((n+6)^2+6(n+6)+18)}{(n^2-6n+18)(n^2+6n+18)} \\
&= \frac{(n^2+6n+18)((n+6)^2+6(n+6)+18)}{(n^2-6n+18)(n^2+6n+18)} \\
&=\dfrac{(n+6)^2+6(n+6)+18}{n^2-6n+18}
\end{align*}$$
which means that most of the terms cancel and we are left with
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{(10^4+324)(22^4+324)(34^4+324)(46^4+324)(58^4+324)}{(4^4+324)(16^4+324)(28^4+324)(40^4+324)(52^4+324)} \\
&\qquad = \frac{(52+6)^2+6(52+6)+18}{4^2-6(4)+18} = \frac{3730}{10}=373
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Because, considering $P(n)=n(n+6)+18$, one sees that $n^2-6n+18=P(n-6)$ and $(n+6)^2+6(n+6)+18=P(n+6)$.